# Apache-like directory listing fallback in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have been switching over to nginx from Apache, and one thing that I found convenient was being able to put an 'index.html' file in a directory and have that be served, but if no such file was present, Apache would generate a directory listing. I have been able to get nginx to do directory listing, but it ignores index.html files. Has anyone been able to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired state is the normal behavior of Nginx autoindex:

> Usually a request is passed to the [`ngx_http_autoindex_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) module
>   when the [`ngx_http_index_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html) module cannot find an index file.
>
> Syntax:   `autoindex on | off;` Default:  `autoindex off;` Context:    http,
>   server, location
>
> Enables or disables the directory listing output.

And the default for index files is `index index.html;`.

You probably have configured something else for  `index` somewhere in your configuration, which you haven't provided. It would have worked, if you had:

```
location / { 
   index index.html; 
   autoindex on;
}
```